# how the Hough transform could be used to detect a car in an image, given a 3D model of that car?

Tags: image, image-processing

The Hough transform is a classic algorithm for detecting lines, circles, ellipses and any other shape that can be formally described as a series of parameters.

so my intuition tells me that u will break down the car into smaller shapes for examples 
combinations of squares , rectangles , lines and circles .and possibly derive a mathematical equation for the car which can then be used to detect the car ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly put, using only Hough probably won't work unless you view the vehicle from the same angle and at the same distance all the time. Even then, practical considerations of optics, lighting, and dealing with false edges will prevent Hough from working well in anything resembling the real world.

Scaling alone can present a problem. For example, imagine you took an image of the car from a distance of 4 meters, and then again with the same camera and (fixed focal length) lens at a distance of 8 meters from the same view angle. If you were to use Hough, you would have to add a scaling parameter, so instead of parameters (p1, p2, p3,..,pN) you would have (p1, p2, p3, ..., pN, p(N+1)). That would greatly increase the size of the solution space and the memory consumed. Using an image pyramid here wouldn't help much.

If you capture images from the side of the car, then the shapes won't be relevant when you view the car from the front. Increasing the number of shapes to match will make a colossal mess of the software.

Consistent illumination of a car for image processing is much more difficult than most people would imagine. You won't get a simple set of edges because the car will reflect objects from the environment, and the reflections will introduce false edges and apparent color changes. Reflections from the glass will be a problem, too. An algorithm that works a little bit on a red car may fail miserably on a black or white car of the same model.

If you want to detect a car, then one method would be a "bag of words" technique that describes cars and car-like objects as description vectors. You can then search images for blogs or regions of pixels that provided the best match to the description vector.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision

I've seen this type of technique working in a demo. The system was trained to recognize a vehicle in one video, and then it could recognize similar vehicles in an arbitrarily large number of other videos capture with different equipment at different times.

Before you look for a solution, try to define the problem as precisely as you possible can. Do you want to include land-based vehicles of any size, or just passenger vehicles? Dozens of models? Hundreds of models? Thousands of models? Or do you just want to identify whether something is probably a car? Where do you want to detect a car? At what times of day?

And so on.

Comment: Nice answer. You can also use openCV's latent SVM detector with the "car" model. 

You can also try this post about Bag of words :
http://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/bag-of-words-models-for-visual-categorization/